# How do I compare a current element with a previous element within a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

For example, let's say I have the following:

```
array = ['even','even','odd','even','odd','even']
```

How do I write a code  which loops through array in order to check `if array[i] != array[i+1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
array = ['even','even','odd','even','odd','even'] 

for i in range(len(array)-1):
    if array[i] != array[i+1]:
        print("blabla")
```

or

```
for i in range(1, len(array)):
    if array[i] != array[i-1]:
        print("blabla")
```